# How can I export a specific portion of a SwiftUI view and retain all styling and layout using ShareLink?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-sharelink

The goal is to utilize SwiftUI `ShareLink` to render, and share a specific portion of a SwiftUI View to Messages, Instagram, and other social media applications. My question is, what is the appropriate method to do so and retain all styling of that portion of the view?

```swift
struct SelectedEntryShareView: View {
    let title: String
    let entry: String
    let entryDate: Date
    @State private var renderedImage = Image("")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            content
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color("Base"))
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            shareButtons
        }
        .task {
            if !title.isEmpty && !entry.isEmpty {
                renderedImage = renderContent(content: content)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SelectedEntryShareView {
    var content: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text(entryDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))
                    .font(.callout)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundStyle(.accent)
                    .padding(.top)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                Text(entry)
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
                SelectedEntryShareViewFooter()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 300, maxWidth: 400, minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 500)
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Highlight"))
        }
    }
    var shareButtons: some View {
        HStack {
            ShareLink(item: renderedImage, preview: SharePreview(title, image: renderedImage)) {
                Image(systemName: "message.circle")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .background {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    }
            }
            
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .background {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    }
            }
        }
        .font(.title)
    }
    
    @MainActor func renderContent(content: some View) -> Image {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: content)
        guard let image = renderer.uiImage else { fatalError() }
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a function which renders the content into a UIImage, then converts it to an Image. I wasn't sure what to do to pass the image to the ShareLink so I opted for a `@State` variable which is then changed. The current method leaves me with a blank rectangle shown below. I have also included a picture of what I want my desired output to be similar to.

[image: Current Output][image: Desired Outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-a-swiftui-view-to-a-pdf) article. I was able to determine that I needed to add `@MainActor` to the view I was attempting to use `ImageRenderer` on. This allowed me to then call my asynchronous `ImageRenderer` function directly inside of the `ShareLink`.